# Check if a string contains an email address?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string, parsing

How can I check to verify that a given string contains an email address.

The email address would be included with a lot of other text, as well.

Also, not looking to necessarily strictly validate the email address itself. More so just wanting to make sure that `a@b.xyz` is present.

Example string:

```
Overall I liked the service, but had trouble using the widget generator.

Want more info? You can contact me at bob@example.org.
```

Plain javascript is fine, but I do happen to be using jQuery, so if there's some sort of helper function that makes this easier...go for it.

Comment: What @WesleyMurch said. I'm looking for javascript here. Not PHP.

Comment: @WesleyMurch Ah bullocks, my bad :( but regular expressions work in JavaScript too.

Comment: FWIW, this post is already #1 in Google for "[javascript check if a string contains an email address](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+check+if+a+string+contains+an+email+address)". A good answer would be helpful, rather than dismissing the question because it's sort of related to another one.

Comment: You could also check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37684/how-to-replace-plain-urls-with-links/7123542#7123542)

Comment: Regular expressions aside, this is a Javascript question with a prominent php reference....  triggered!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Debuggex Example](http://www.debuggex.com/?re=%28%28%5B%5E%3C%3E%28%29%5B%5C%5D%5C%5C.,;%3a%5Cs@%5C%22%5D%2b%28%5C.%5B%5E%3C%3E%28%29%5B%5C%5D%5C%5C.,;%3a%5Cs@%5C%22%5D%2b%29%2a%29%7C%28%5C%0A%22.%2b%5C%22%29%29@%28%28%5C%5B%5B0-9%5D%7B1,3%7D%5C.%5B0-9%5D%7B1,3%7D%5C.%5B0-9%5D%7B1,3%7D%5C.%5B0-9%5D%7B1,3%7D%5C%5D%29%7C%28%28%5Ba-zA%0A-Z%5C-0-9%5D%2b%5C.%29%2b%5Ba-zA-Z%5D%7B2,%7D%29%29&flags=&str=The%20email%20in%20this%20string%20is%20yomama@yomama.com%20)

[JsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/tJk34/)

```
function checkIfEmailInString(text) { 
    var re = /(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))/;
    return re.test(text);
}
```

Comment: On the negative of this it doesn't match new lines, any ideas how to amend this? https://regex101.com/r/rN6eD6/1

Answer (score 8):

You can use this:

```
var StrObj = "whatever, this is my email dave@gmail.com other text";
var emailsArray = StrObj.match(/([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)/gi);
if (emailsArray != null && emailsArray.length) {
    //has email
}
```

This also lets you get the email address from the array, if you need it.

Comment: this won't work at least for cyrilic email addresses, maybe for some other as well. e.g. emails from this domain - https://админ.com

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
/\b[a-z0-9-_.]+@[a-z0-9-_.]+(\.[a-z0-9]+)+/i.test(text)
```